# ImportError: No module named 'pandas.indexes'

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, pickle

Importing pandas didn't throw the error, but rather trying to read a picked pandas dataframe as such:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")

control_data = pd.read_pickle('null_report.pickle')
test_data = pd.read_pickle('test_report.pickle')
```

The traceback is 165 lines with three concurrent exceptions (whatever that means).  Is `read_pickle` not compatible with pandas version 17.1 I'm running?  How do I unpickle my dataframe for use?

Below is a copy of the traceback:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py in try_read(path, encoding)
     45             with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
---> 46                 return pkl.load(fh)
     47         except (Exception) as e:

ImportError: No module named 'pandas.indexes'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py in try_read(path, encoding)
     51                 with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
---> 52                     return pc.load(fh, encoding=encoding, compat=False)
     53 

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\pickle_compat.py in load(fh, encoding, compat, is_verbose)
    115 
--> 116         return up.load()
    117     except:

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in load(self)
   1038                 assert isinstance(key, bytes_types)
-> 1039                 dispatch[key[0]](self)
   1040         except _Stop as stopinst:

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in load_stack_global(self)
   1342             raise UnpicklingError("STACK_GLOBAL requires str")
-> 1343         self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
   1344     dispatch[STACK_GLOBAL[0]] = load_stack_global

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in find_class(self, module, name)
   1383                 module = _compat_pickle.IMPORT_MAPPING[module]
-> 1384         __import__(module, level=0)
   1385         if self.proto >= 4:

ImportError: No module named 'pandas.indexes'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py in read_pickle(path)
     59     try:
---> 60         return try_read(path)
     61     except:

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py in try_read(path, encoding)
     56                 with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
---> 57                     return pc.load(fh, encoding=encoding, compat=True)
     58 

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\pickle_compat.py in load(fh, encoding, compat, is_verbose)
    115 
--> 116         return up.load()
    117     except:

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in load(self)
   1038                 assert isinstance(key, bytes_types)
-> 1039                 dispatch[key[0]](self)
   1040         except _Stop as stopinst:

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in load_stack_global(self)
   1342             raise UnpicklingError("STACK_GLOBAL requires str")
-> 1343         self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
   1344     dispatch[STACK_GLOBAL[0]] = load_stack_global

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in find_class(self, module, name)
   1383                 module = _compat_pickle.IMPORT_MAPPING[module]
-> 1384         __import__(module, level=0)
   1385         if self.proto >= 4:

ImportError: No module named 'pandas.indexes'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py in try_read(path, encoding)
     45             with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
---> 46                 return pkl.load(fh)
     47         except (Exception) as e:

ImportError: No module named 'pandas.indexes'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py in try_read(path, encoding)
     51                 with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
---> 52                     return pc.load(fh, encoding=encoding, compat=False)
     53 

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\pickle_compat.py in load(fh, encoding, compat, is_verbose)
    115 
--> 116         return up.load()
    117     except:

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in load(self)
   1038                 assert isinstance(key, bytes_types)
-> 1039                 dispatch[key[0]](self)
   1040         except _Stop as stopinst:

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in load_stack_global(self)
   1342             raise UnpicklingError("STACK_GLOBAL requires str")
-> 1343         self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
   1344     dispatch[STACK_GLOBAL[0]] = load_stack_global

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in find_class(self, module, name)
   1383                 module = _compat_pickle.IMPORT_MAPPING[module]
-> 1384         __import__(module, level=0)
   1385         if self.proto >= 4:

ImportError: No module named 'pandas.indexes'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-3b05fe7d20a4> in <module>()
      3 # test_data = np.genfromtxt(fh, usecols=2)
      4 
----> 5 control_data = pd.read_pickle('null_report.pickle')
      6 test_data = pd.read_pickle('test_report.pickle')
      7 

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py in read_pickle(path)
     61     except:
     62         if PY3:
---> 63             return try_read(path, encoding='latin1')
     64         raise

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py in try_read(path, encoding)
     55             except:
     56                 with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
---> 57                     return pc.load(fh, encoding=encoding, compat=True)
     58 
     59     try:

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\pickle_compat.py in load(fh, encoding, compat, is_verbose)
    114         up.is_verbose = is_verbose
    115 
--> 116         return up.load()
    117     except:
    118         raise

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in load(self)
   1037                     raise EOFError
   1038                 assert isinstance(key, bytes_types)
-> 1039                 dispatch[key[0]](self)
   1040         except _Stop as stopinst:
   1041             return stopinst.value

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in load_stack_global(self)
   1341         if type(name) is not str or type(module) is not str:
   1342             raise UnpicklingError("STACK_GLOBAL requires str")
-> 1343         self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
   1344     dispatch[STACK_GLOBAL[0]] = load_stack_global
   1345 

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in find_class(self, module, name)
   1382             elif module in _compat_pickle.IMPORT_MAPPING:
   1383                 module = _compat_pickle.IMPORT_MAPPING[module]
-> 1384         __import__(module, level=0)
   1385         if self.proto >= 4:
   1386             return _getattribute(sys.modules[module], name)[0]

ImportError: No module named 'pandas.indexes'
```

I also tried loading the pickle file from pickle directly:

`via_pickle = pickle.load( open( 'null_report.pickle', "rb" ) )`

and got the same error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-ba2e3adae1c4> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 via_pickle = pickle.load( open( 'null_report.pickle', "rb" ) )
      3 
      4 # control_data = pd.read_pickle('null_report.pickle')
      5 # test_data = pd.read_pickle('test_report.pickle')

ImportError: No module named 'pandas.indexes'
```

Comment: I think you need to load an older version of pandas to unpickle this.  Then save as csv or something else.  Pickle depends on class structure and module pointing to reconstruct the object.  If this structure changes, pickle will break.

Comment: you are trying to read a newer pickle with an older version of pandas. pandas.indexes doesn't exist until 0.18.0; pandas offers back compat not forward compat (meaning a newer versions can read older, but older cannot read newer)

Comment: I am using 0.20.2, and have this problem with a pickle that was generated with an older version.

Comment: I'm using 0.20.3 and getting this error with an older pickle file too.

Comment: @r3robertson try using `pd.read_pickle`, as indicated [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16474#issuecomment-303676808)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I had this error when I created a pkl file with python 2.7 and was trying to read it with python 3.6
I did:

```
pd.read_pickle('foo.pkl')
```

and it worked

Comment: I believe this should be the correct answer. This works in most cases, while upgrading `pandas` doesn't.

Comment: nice work. Thanks. With the same version of pandas, this problem also happens. But `pd.read_pickle` works.

Answer (score 17):

I had this problem from trying to open a pickled dataframe made with pandas 0.18.1 using pandas 0.17.1.
If you are using pip, upgrade pandas with:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

If you are using a library like anaconda, use:

```
conda upgrade pandas
```

If you need to have both versions of pandas on your machine, consider using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Worked for me. It's a small detail, but I had to use pip3 install --upgrade pandas to ensure it worked on Python 3.

Answer (score 9):

Saving and loading in different versions of `pandas` using `pickle` often does not work. Instead, use [`pandas.HDFStore`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#hdf5-pytables).

When I needed to update pandas but also needed some data saved with pickle in previous versions, I went back and re-saved that data in HDF format instead, when nothing else would work. No problems anymore.

Works for any sort of pandas data structure it seems, even multi-indexed dataframes! In short, if pickling fails after a version upgrade, try HDFStore; it's more reliable (and more efficient!).

Comment: Didn't even know about this method, which could perhaps also then be opened in `R`.

Comment: Thankyou for calling this to our attention. Just one nit, however. HDFStore was designed for pandas objects. If you want to store, say, a Python dictionary, you have to do some kudgey stuff, like store a stub DataFrame then add the dictionary object to it as an "attribute", as recommended in the pandas cookbook (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#hdfstore). I personally never got this kludge to work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution without updating pandas or whatever your using.

If you're using python2

```
import cPickle
with open('filename.pkl', 'rb') as fo:
        dict = cPickle.load(fo, encoding='latin1’)
```

If you're using python3

```
import pickle
with open('filename.pkl', 'rb') as fo:
        dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='latin1’)
```

Comment: Your python3 solution doesn't work for me, it gives a `UnicodeDecodeError` on the last line,` 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte.`

Comment: still gives me ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.indexes' on python3.6

Answer (score 1):

In the pandas 0.23.4, there is a better way to fix the problem. Use the `pandas.read_pickle` to read the fileobject, like:

`pd.read_pickle(open('test_report.pickle', 'rb'))`

Answer (score 1):

A flexible way to deal with internal API changes that break unpickling is to implement a custom Unpickler instance.

For example, the `pandas.indexes` module has been moved to `pandas.core.indexes`. We can write an Unpickler, that adapts the module path accordingly. To do that, we can overwrite the method `find_class`:

```
import sys
class Unpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    def find_class(self, module, name):
        '''This method gets called for every module pickle tries to load.'''
        # python 2 --> 3 compatibility: __builtin__ has been renamed to builtins
        if module == '__builtin__':
            module = 'builtins'
        # pandas compatibility: in newer versions, pandas.indexes has been moved to pandas.core.indexes
        if 'pandas.indexes' in module:
            module = module.replace('pandas.indexes', 'pandas.core.indexes')
        __import__(module)
        return getattr(sys.modules[module], name)

with open('/path/to/pickle.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    pdf = Unpickler(file).load()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read pickled text instead of a file, do

```
import io

pd.read_pickle(io.BytesIO(pickled_text))
```

If you face the error - `ValueError: Unrecognized compression type: infer`,
explicitly mention the compression type. It could be one of None(no compression), gzip, bz2, xz or zip(depending upon file extension).
`pd.read_pickle(io.BytesIO(pickled_text), compression=None)`