# What is the difference between save a pandas dataframe to pickle and to csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pickle

I am learning python pandas.
I see a tutorial which shows two ways to save a pandas dataframe.

1. `pd.to_csv('sub.csv')` and to open `pd.read_csv('sub.csv')`
2. `pd.to_pickle('sub.pkl')` and to open `pd.read_pickle('sub.pkl')`

The tutorial says `to_pickle` is to save the dataframe to disk. I am confused about this. Because when I use `to_csv`, I did see a csv file appears in the folder, which I assume is also save to disk right?

In general, why we want to save a dataframe using `to_pickle` rather than save it to csv or txt or other format?

Comment: Matthew Rocklin does an interesting speed analysis [here](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/03/16/Fast-Serialization)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Pickle is a serialized way of storing a Pandas dataframe. Basically, you are  writing down the exact representation of the dataframe to disk. This means the types of the columns are and the indices are the same. If you simply save a file as `csv`, you are just storing it as a comma separated list. Depending on your data set, some information will be lost when you load it back up.

You can read more about pickle library in python, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Comment: So you mean, to_pickle should be more preferable when saving a pandas dataframe, i.e., it preserves the original dataframe? Are there any advantages of to_pickle? for example, in terms of loading speed?

Comment: @KevinKim, you may want to check [this comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010212/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-upload-a-big-csv-file-in-notebook-to-work-with-python)

Comment: The main advantage of saving in CSV would be having a standardized format that can be opened with a wide range of software/languages

Comment: @MaxU Thanks! So if my original data set is a large csv file, I guess it would be good to first load it into pandas and then store it using to_pickle. Hence, next time when I need to load this dataframe again, I can use read_pickle to load it must faster, is that correct?

Comment: @Alessandro yes, that makes sense, I agree with you

Answer (score 57):

#### *csv*

- ✅human readable
- ✅cross platform
- ⛔slower
- ⛔more disk space
- ⛔doesn't preserve types in some cases

#### *pickle*

- ✅fast saving/loading
- ✅less disk space
- ⛔non human readable
- ⛔python only
- ⛔sensitive to version changes

#### Also take a look at *parquet* format (`to_parquet`, `read_parquet`)

- ✅fast saving/loading
- ✅less disk space than *pickle*
- ✅supported by many platforms
- ⛔non human readable

Comment: Also take a look at _feather_ format (`to_feather`, `read_feather`) According to a [TDS review](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d) it "shows high I/O speed, doesn’t take too much memory on the disk and doesn’t need any unpacking when loaded back into RAM."

Comment: Thanks this answer is very concise and to the point. For a detailed breakdown, I found [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d) that does an indepth breakdown, including `to_feather` vs `to_parquet`

Comment: one thing I would add into comparison is **[pickle incompatibility risk between different Python/pandas versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371451/importerror-no-module-named-pandas-indexes)** (CSV data will always remain readable). i.e., my workstation at office is old and uses Python 3.4: its highest pandas version cannot handle pickle pandas dataframes generated by my Python 3.8 at home. So CSV is a better choice when you cannot control all pandas versions that will be using your files. In summary: **CSV is** not only "cross platform" but **also "cross versions"**

Comment: Another [useful article about pickle](https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-using-csvs-for-storage-pickle-is-an-80-times-faster-alternative-832041bbc199)

Comment: Well, I loved the clarity of this beautiful answer, but I concur with Abu about the version issues with Pandas. It has tripped me up.  Also, well I started to use the pickle approach for speed and space.... but strangely I do NOT find my pickles smaller. Just experimentally saved a strip of annotated ECG: 272.1MB (pickle), but 155.8MB (csv).  That said, writing and reading the pickle took only 0.48s and the csv took a very irritating 11.49s !!