# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.indexes' when loading old pickle in new python

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

NOT A DUPLICATE!!!
It is NOT A DUPLICATE because: 1. I am using pickle to loads, and not pandas as the original question. 2. upgrading pandas does not help. 3. the original question was using the very same thing the accepted answer suggested. 4. other answers suggest changing the file which is not an option

---

I have an old pickle file I have to read.

I am reading using

```
def loads(s):
    try:
        content = pickle.loads(s)
    except TypeError:
        content = pickle.loads(str.encode(s), encoding='latin1')
    return content
```

reading the pickle fails the `try` (as expected), and then enters the `except`.

It then fails with

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.indexes'

How can I read that old pickle?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'pandas.indexes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371451/importerror-no-module-named-pandas-indexes)

Comment: No. It doesn't solve it because I have to read with `loads`, and not from file

Comment: Please vote to reopen this question! It is NOT A DUPLICATE because: 1. I am using pickle to loads, and not pandas as the original question. 2. upgrading pandas does not help. 3. the original question was using the very same thing the accepted answer suggested. 4. other answers suggest changing the file which is not an option.

Comment: _2. upgrading pandas does not help._ Upgrading to which version? How was the pickle created?

Comment: did you import pandas in the environment your are unpickling from?

Comment: @AMC latest pandas version. `pip install pandas`, `pip install --upgrade pandas`. pandas 0.25.3

Comment: @MarkusRotherthe pickle was created with pandas 0.19.0